# What style is this font?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

What's the name for this style of lettering? It makes me think of Victorian, but I wonder if there's a name for this particular style?

Also, can anyone help me find this font?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Victorian, sure, but I thought it would sub-set a little further than that, I went with 2 searches - **wild west** & **circus**.

I found this under circus…

[image]

Romantiques - https://www.1001fonts.com/romantiques-font.html
It looks to be all-caps, no lower case.

Answer (score 1):

**Ornate** or **Decorative** are common descriptors.

There's no universally used name for such characters.

Answer (score 0):

Decorated would be OK. Types like this are often used in multicolor layered printing and lettering, so searching ["chromatic"](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/408279522450146435/) would also find you types in the same style.